# Merge results to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  a.User1 as Employee
        , isnull(sum(distinct b.Page_Count),0) AS Yesterday
        , isnull(sum(distinct c.Page_Count),0) AS Today
        , isnull(sum(distinct d.Page_Count),0) AS Week
        , e.Material_Location as '(Yesterday)'
        , f.Material_Location as '(Today)'
From    TaskUser AS a
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS b
    ON b.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND b.Date_Assigned between ('06/09/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS c
    ON c.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND c.Date_Assigned between ('06/13/2014') AND ('06/14/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS d
    ON d.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND d.Date_Assigned between ('06/09/2014') AND ('06/14/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS e
    ON e.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND e.Date_Assigned between ('06/12/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS f
    ON f.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND f.Date_Assigned between ('06/13/2014') AND ('06/14/2014')
GROUP BY a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
Order By a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
```

If multiple records were input for the same user on the same day, I am getting unique rows for the same person. I only want one row per user with the e and f results merged to the same column.

Ie: Current Output =

```
Amy   0   640   640   NoTask   Task  
Amy   0   640   640   Task2    Task  
Amy   0   640   640   Task3    Task4  
Amy   0   640   640   Task1    NoTask
```

Requested output:

```
Amy   0   640   640   (NoTask, Task1, Task2, Task3) (NoTask, Task, Task4)
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using? You may be looking for a pivot query.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that (new to sql)

Comment: First off, what data base system are you using? some examples are mysql, sql server/mssql/tsql, postgresql, db2, oracle, derby, sqlite, teradata, sybase...

Comment: Also, if you are new to a knowledge area, google will speed up your learning curve a lot: https://www.google.com/search?q=rdbms https://www.google.com/search?q=pivot%20query

Comment: I suggest adding an sql fiddle to your question so people can see the data you're working with: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a group_contact() function. It's got `STUFF` though.

Comment: [Stop using between!](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a greatly over-simplified example of using [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) combined with a [correlated subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15ca7/6)

I used your output as a table, more or less:

```
select
name,
 stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + mt.one
    from MyTable mt
      WHERE mt.name = t1.name
    order by mt.name
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') 
from mytable t1
group by name
```

We're using stuff to concatenate each value for the column I creatively named `ONE` for each `NAME`.  The correlated subquery allows us to relate each row coming out of that to the corresponding row coming out of the main query.